# How to assign PHP variable to html table cell id

Tags: php, html-table

I am trying to assign dynamic id to table cell in PHP but it does not seem to be working.

```
<?php   $var="23,24,25";
        echo $var."\n";
?>

<table id="summary-table" border =1 cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:100%">
<th>Col1</th><th>Col2</th><th>Ids</th>
  <tr>
    <td>Row1</td>
    <td>A</td>       
    <td id="td-containing-ids" data-ids="23278,62157,325845,568673,607607"><font color="blue">3</font></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row2</td>
    <td>B</td>       
    <!-- trying to add php value to td id  --->
    <td id="td-containing-ids" data-ids= '<?php $var ?>' ><font color="blue">4</font></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
</table>
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: change <?php $var ?> this to <?php echo  $var; ?>

Comment: `data-ids="<?php echo $var; ?>"`

Answer (score 3):

hi you should add echo

```
<td id="td-containing-ids" data-ids= '<?php echo $var ?>' >
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

you've already set the id as 'td-containing-ids'. if you want to asign the data-id you'd need

```
 <td id="td-containing-ids" data-ids='<?php echo $var ?>' >
    <font color="blue">4</font>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Where ever you want the String you have to echo it into the HTML. Like this

```
<td data-ids='<?echo$var;?>'>
```

also don't forget your syntax!

Comment: Pls don't downvote as i am new to this web development. I am C++ programmer and switching to web development.

Comment: I didn't :p PHP is sort of similar to C# in the way that it's classes are structured etc. Compared to C++ it's very different.